# css text rotate - text only , not parent element

Tags: css, text, rotation

on this page: https://www.bcidaho.com/mammography/

if you click "find a screening center" a table of information comes up...

how can i rotate the text in the last 5 cells?

obviously cross browser would help... this would allow the table to fit properly...

and do i have to set a height on the TDs to make it fit right?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page: https://www.udemy.com/blog/css-rotate-text/
in the section "Rotating Text with CSS Transform Property".

You have to create a `class` or `id` in your CSS file, and apply it to the text you want to rotate, not the `div`.

Comment: Note that the OP commented on the other answer that css text rotation, as in your answer, does not work in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

The link the question no longer works. I'm going to assume the use case is that you want to rotate text within e.g. a div, without messing up the div's width, height, x, y, background, etc. E.g., If you were to rotate the div directly, its background would also be rotated.

1 solution is to nest a rotated element within the parent element.

```css
.parent {
  margin: 100px; 
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}

div {
  outline: 1px solid red;
 
}

.child {
  transform-origin: center left;
  transform: rotate(300deg) translate(-25px, 25px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Text label
  </div>
</div>
```